# How do I print full path?

Tags: 7, theming, emails

My current code works:

```
<img src="<?php print $base_url . '/' . drupal_get_path('theme', 'lapost'); ?>/images/cart-template-logo.png" />
```

But if you check in source it prints only `/sites/all/themes/lapost/images/cart-template-logo.png`

It works if you load image on-site, but it also gets sent to email and when mail arrives it gives dead image shortcut, because the path is missing the www.webaddress.com part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [url()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7):

```
$imgurl = drupal_get_path('theme', 'YOURTHEME') . '/images/image.png';
$final_url = url($imgurl, array('absolute' => TRUE));
```

This will provide a url like http://example.com/sites/all/themes/YOURTHEME/images/image.png

Comment: Hi, it still gives only 'sites/all/themes/lapost/images/cart-template-logo.png' and with no starting / so it gives dead url.

Comment: Hello! Oh! could you please try to output the value of $final_url in drupal_set_messag() maybe and see if there's any difference?

Comment: Umm sorry for wasting your time, but I found a dirty workaround that works and prints full path in source and looks cleaner: <?php print token_replace('[site:url]'); ?>

Comment: No problem at all! Learned something too! Glad you got it working!

Comment: This is the correct way. +1. @OptimusPrime you have to use the `$final_url` variable. Not the `$imgurl` (that is, if you copy-pasted the above code). 
Note that token replace comes with a great cost (parsing, replacing, hook calls, etc), and url() is built with performance in mind.

Comment: @AyeshK Wow! I didn't know that token_replace greatly hits the performance but I notice site with so many tokens in the node's edit page that sometimes the page exhausts more memory. Thanks for the additional into too!

Answer (score 0):

Use [base_path](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/base_path/7) to get full url of site

> Returns the base URL path (i.e., directory) of the Drupal
>   installation.

The base_url global contains the base_path of the drupal installation, and this might be a subdirectory like 'drupal'. If you don't need this, there's another global variable named 'base_root', which doesn't contain the base path:

```
$GLOBALS['base_url'] => http://example.com/drupal
$GLOBALS['base_root'] => http://example.com
```

By the way, perhaps one should use the global variables supplied by Drupal, so instead of using

```
$root = $GLOBALS['base_root']
```

we should better use

```
global $base_root;
$root = $base_root;
```

If you get image file path then you use this

There is catch here, for example if you want to use get url of http://example.com/files/logo.png, than use

```
$url = base_path() .'files/logo.png';
```

If you write this

```
$url = base_path() .'/files/logo.png';
```

It will return - http://files/log.png. which is incorrect.